# React.cloneElement() in react native not keeping original props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Have an element that wraps several rows of cell elements, its purpose is simply for styling the bottom borders (really missing css :last-child in react native).

The cell element exists elsewhere and can be used independent of the wrapper if the devs choose, so this wrapper is just an optional addition if they are making a list of cell rows and need border style formatting.

The cell elements pipe in sub elements as props and render them so you've got cell button things with text/whatever passed on the left and an arrow on the right, pretty typical [iphone list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3slsX.png) .

The following works mostly (even the last child border style logic is working) except the sub element props are not preserved in the clone for some reason, so the output rather than being "some sub El text" then an ">", it is only showing the ">".  Code included below (stripped out most styling for readability)

Cell elements:

```
class Cell extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

render() {
    styles = [styles.container];
    if(!this.props.isLastChild) {
      styles.push({borderBottomWidth: 0});
    }

    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={styles}>
          {this.props.subElements}
          <Text> > </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
     );
   }
};
```

Wrapper:

```
const Wrapper = () => {

  const childCount = React.Children.count(children);
  return (<View>
     {React.Children.map(children, (c, i) => 
        React.cloneElement(c, {
          isLastChild: i === childCount - 1,
        })
      )}</View>);
}
```

Usage:

```
const subEl = 
    <View>
      <Text>Blah</Text>
      <Text>La La La</Text>
    </View>

  <View>
      <Wrapper>
        <Cell subElements={subEl} />
        <Cell subElements={subEl} />
      </Wrapper>
  </View>
```

Comment: What is `subEl` in `<Cell subElements={subEl} />` - Could you give an example, is it a String value? Another component?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, originally it was named child- edited to correct.

Comment: when i use Cell without the wrapper, the subEl renders fine if that helps at all

Comment: It renders for me on https://snack.expo.io/r1b90mWXf - I see the subEl being rendered.

Comment: restarted the server and it worked, guess it was good all along.  Thanks!